# How to use NSSet<Class> in Swift (exported as Set<NSObject>)?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsobject

I have to fulfill a protocol requirement that is defined in Objective-C like this:

```
@protocol AProtocol <NSObject>
+ (NSSet<Class> * _Nullable)someClasses;
@end
```

I want to implement this protocol in a subclass written in Swift. I want to return a Set of classes of another Object. The class I want to return is defined like this:

```
class B: NSObject {}
```

The class that conforms to the protocol is defined like this:

```
class A: NSObject, AProtocol {
    static func someClasses() -> Set<NSObject>? {
        return [B.self]
    }
}
```

Why is `NSSet<Class>` bridged to `Set<NSObject>` instead of Set?

This solution is crashing, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: One question, I don't see how returning `Set<NSObject>?` fulfills the `NSSet<Class>` return type on the protocol. Shouldn't that be `Set<AnyClass>`? Also, please include declaration for the AppDelegate type.

Comment: @PatrickGoley yeah, I totally understand the confusion, this confused me as well. As someone explained me: Class is just an object in Objective-C, that's why this is bridged like this. I think they are bridging it in other cases to AnyClass but since AnyClass does not conform to Hashable (which is precondition for Set) that was not possible. Xcode generates the interface for the protocol like this.
AppDelegate is just generated by Xcode, I add it to the original post.

Comment: Ok, the problem itself is solved, I will edit the question and add the answer, maybe it's helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSSet<Class>` is bridged to `Set<NSObject>` because `AnyClass` does not conform to `Hashable` which is a precondition for the `ValueType` of `Set`.

It can be solved with the following extension for `NSObjectProtocol`:

```
extension NSObjectProtocol where Self: NSObject {
    static var objcClass: NSObject {
        return (self as AnyObject) as! NSObject
    }
}
```

This returns the class of the object casted as `NSObject`. It is necessary to cast it first to `AnyObject` because the type system of Swift is so strong that it would not compile or give a warning when directly casting a type to an instance type. In Objective-C this is fine because `Class` is also just an object. Since `NSObject` is implemented in Objective-C and the extension is just for `NSObjectProtocol`, this is save to use (even with the force cast).
Implementing the extension on `NSObjectProtocol` and not on `NSObject` itself brings the positive effect that it is not exported to Objective-C.